# reCaptcha2 cross origin issue in google chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, recaptcha

I am using the Google reCaptcha2 in my Rails app using the `gem 'recaptcha'`. Its working in all browsers except the Chrome. It produces an error as given below in the browser console.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

This was working a few days back and suddenly stopped working. I am doing anything wrong withe configuration or initialization of the captcha

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to this, but I believe I have a similar problem. I'll just add what I have discovered so far and hopefully it will help. If I solve my problem I will update.

Had reCaptcha 2 working on a site I am developing. It's a SPA (using Vue.js). It has at some point stopped working (not sure when the issue started), with the error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

So then using `https` protocol, I get the error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

It is working completely fine in Firefox and Safari.

Testing versions of Chrome - it doesn't work in 52 or 51. **It starts working again in Chrome 50.**

Something else I have found is if I just create an HTML file with nothing but reCaptcha 2 in it and serve it over `http` - it works in anything.